# Will ground sealed pepper have lost it freshness?

Tags: fresh, pepper

From other answers I can see that fine grounded pepper looses its freshness and flavors so freshly ground is better.

1. Does this apply as much to coarse ground, I imagine when you bite it more parts of the pepper is newly exposed and the flavour will be better?
2. With some containers of fine ground i notice, after removing the lid there is a seal with foil paper.  I imagine the fine grounded it and immediately sealed with foil paper to keep freshness and non exposure to air.  Would the foil paper actually make a difference or should I consider finely ground in a bottle with foil paper still to have lost most of its flavour like those in packets?

Comment: It's like coffee. Once ground it starts to lose flavour & aroma. You cannot buy ready-ground coffee that's anywhere near as good as fresh-ground, no matter how much some very experienced manufacturers try.

Answer (score 8):

Ground pepper begins to lose it's flavors very quickly.  You can try this yourself by grinding your own, then tasting over the course of a couple of days.  I find it is always best right after I grind it.  Sealing a container of ground pepper might help, but who knows how long between grinding and sealing? Then, once you remove the seal, flavor is degrading further. Again, just compare this pepper to some you have freshly ground.  There really is no comparison.  If you are a black pepper lover, buy whole and grind in small amounts.

Comment: Buy a pepper mill... buy two! One fine for the table & one coarser & faster for cooking. I actually have 4 in my kitchen, I also have one for multi-coloured pepper & another for szechuan.

Comment: Buy a corn-mill. Motorize it, or not. Set it on fine setting. Get some Ziyad pepper corns at the Arab store, about $3.50 for 5oz. Put it through your grinder. You'll get excellent quality, fresh ground pepper, plus you'll have the equipment you need to make real corn tortillas.